# Openchain returns error when submitting a mutation

Tags: python, cryptography, blockchain

I am trying to submit  a mutation in our Openchain server without success. I suppose my address and keys are not correct. below is the code that i think may have the problem.

```
def get_mutation(namespace, path, value):
    r = openchain_pb2.Record()
    m = openchain_pb2.Mutation()
    m.namespace = namespace
    rv = openchain_pb2.RecordValue()
    rx=m.records.add()
    rv.data = value
    rx.value.CopyFrom(rv)
    #r.key = '/p2pkh/XneAi6WTqcubvJaFGN5BRRMPmhBf3xEKew/'
    rx.key = path
    rx.version = sha256('1')
    return m

def submit(session, mutation, pub_key, private_key):
    netopen_submit=urlparse.urljoin(netopenchain_url, "submit")
    mutations = mutation.SerializeToString()
    print "Mutations\t",mutations
    # Hash the mutation byte string using double SHA-256
    final_hash = double_sha256(mutations)

    # Sign it with the private key using Secp256k1
    sig = ecdsa_sign(final_hash, private_key)
    print ecdsa_verify(final_hash, sig, pub_key)

    post_data = dict(
        mutation=binascii.hexlify(mutations),
        signatures=dict(
        # The matching public key must be submitted along with the
        # signature
        pub_key=binascii.hexlify(pub_key),
        signature=binascii.hexlify(sig),
        )
    )
  header = {'content-type' : 'application/json;charset=utf8',"User-                Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome"}
    r = session.post(netopen_submit, headers=header, json= post_data)#
    if r.status_code != 200:
       return -1
    print json.dumps(post_data)
    prepared = r.request
    return r.json()

def getKeysAndAddress(password):
  priv = sha256(password);
  pub = privkey_to_pubkey(priv)
  addr = pubkey_to_address(pub)
  return priv, pub, addr


privatekey,publickey,myaddress = getKeysAndAddress("poverty myself when avocado pink slot unfold appear recall liar teach stand")
mut_buf = get_mutation(netopen_namespace,mypath,'stampnumber9')
submit(session, mut_buf, publickey, privatekey)
```

myaddress is equal to  '1ukGbi7TXMRBiEWefRBfnc9vuPKBmDd6K' after running getKeysAndAddress

However may address shown in the Openchain site is XneAi6WTqcubvJaFGN5BRRMPmhBf3xEKew.
And every time I try to insert a mutation signed by the generated key I receive an error.

Somehow I think that the getKeysAndAddress function is not correct.